# How to correctly ping any website with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs app, i made this service :

```
/* ConnectivityService */
fara.factory('ConnectivityService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource(
        'http://www.google.com/',
        null,
        {
            'check': {method: 'GET', isArray: false, cache: false}
        }
    );
}]);
```

called like that

```
    /* ----- SERVICE ConnectivityService.check(); ----- */
    ConnectivityService.check(function(responseSCon) {

        // show response
        console.log(responseSCon);

    }, function (msg) {
        // final reject
    });
```

but i have this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'my-website-here' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I don't understand, it's not a POST request, it's GET, so why this warning ?

Comment: CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) are forbidden in browser. You should created your own backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to correctly ping any website with angularjs

You can't. XHR is limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Unless the other site plays with you (via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), and provided your user is using a [supporting browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)), you can't play with *it*.